# How to use Microsoft.Build in .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I have the following issue trying to programmatically build a `.vcxproj` from a C# test.

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.IProjectElement' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache..ctor(Boolean autoReloadFromDisk)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, IEnumerable`1 loggers, IEnumerable`1 remoteLoggers, ToolsetDefinitionLocations toolsetDefinitionLocations, Int32 maxNodeCount, Boolean onlyLogCriticalEvents) in E:\A\_work\82\s\src\Build\Definition\ProjectCollection.cs:line 307
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection..ctor() in E:\A\_work\82\s\src\Build\Definition\ProjectCollection.cs:line 252
```

This happens as soon as my code reaches the very first `new ProjectCollection()` expression. I have added the following lines to my `.csproj` file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="15.6.85" />
```

Why is it looking for version 14 for `Microsoft.Build.Framework`? Why can't it load it. I'm on Visual Studio 2017, I get the same results from the `dotnet test` command.

Comment: Probably because `Microsoft.Build.Framework` is another DLL? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework/15.7.0-preview-000145

Comment: @Camilo Adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="15.6.85" />` changes nothing.

Comment: @AlexReinking It's looking for version 14.0 `from assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

Comment: Can you post the code being used to compile? Also, if it's looking for version 14.0, shouldn't you use `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="14.0.0.0" />`?

Comment: Well, I'm asking it to use Microsoft.Build version 15.6.85. Part of the weirdness is that it seems to be trying to load a mismatched version, and I can't figure out why. Referencing 14.0.0.0 also gives the same issue.